# Authentication system for a web service

Tags: authentication, verification

I am building a web service which i will be launching in near future. Service is more or less like online classifieds.
Now, i need to **build a mechanism to collect user's information, enough to trace him** in case of any fraud with other users. I can ask for nation ID card and things like that. But problem is that how will i verify them and the person providing the information.
So, i need suggestions for such system which could be used t authenticate users, so other users can trust them. And contact them freely knowing in case of any mishap authorities can get its information from our service.
For solution we must consider that our service will be free so if this process is costly, than their might be a mechanism to get that cost paid by users.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How can i move it there?
Thankyou for the suggestion

Comment: There's no way to move it by yourself that I'm aware of. Just repost there and delete here.